# Anychart - Stock - Problem with correct date display

Tags: angular, datetime, time, anychart

I have a problem with a correct date time display using AnyChart (stock chart) in Angular.

Sometimes AnyChart displays time correct, but sometimes it's not - I can not understand what it depends on.

The wrong format of datetime is '05 28 Mar 2019' and with the same code is 28 Mar 2019, 05:00

I'v already tried to use date with a time as a string, as a Date and as a Timestamp.

Sometimes it is ok with a tick size less than 500. Sometimes it doesn't work even with a couple ticks.

Sometimes it works when I zoom in a chart.

Code example:

```
draw(tickData: TickData, tickForChart: any[], container: ElementRef) {
  const table = AnyCharts.data.table();
  table.addData(tickForChart);

  const mapping = table.mapAs({
    x: 0,
    open: 1,
    high: 2,
    low: 3,
    close: 4
  });

  const chart = AnyCharts.stock();

  const prices = chart.plot(0).candlestick(mapping);
  prices.name(tickData.market.marketName);
  prices.risingStroke('#3ba158');
  prices.risingFill('#3ba158');
  prices.fallingStroke('#fa1a20');
  prices.fallingFill('#fa0f16');

  chart.plot(0).xGrid().enabled(true);
  chart.plot(0).yGrid().enabled(true);
  chart.plot(0).yGrid().stroke("#dee2e6");

  chart.title(this.getMarketName(tickData));
  chart.container(container.nativeElement);
  chart.scroller(true);
  chart.draw();
  container.nativeElement.style.height = '600px';
  return chart;
}
```

Did anyone have the same problem? How can I fix it?

Also, I attached image with wrong formatting.

[wrong formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWgHg.png)

And with correct:

[Correct formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7xkJ.png)

Like example it works good with data:

```
['2019-03-28T05:00:00', 511.53, 514.98, 505.79, 506.40],
['2019-03-28T05:30:00', 512.53, 514.88, 505.69, 510.34],
['2019-03-28T06:00:00', 511.83, 514.98, 505.59, 507.23],
['2019-03-28T06:30:00', 511.22, 515.30, 505.49, 506.47],
...
```

but failed with data:

```
 ['2015-12-24T08:13:00', 511.53, 514.98, 505.79, 506.40],
 ['2015-12-24T09:13:00', 512.53, 514.88, 505.69, 510.34],
 ['2015-12-24T10:13:00', 511.83, 514.98, 505.59, 507.23],
 ['2015-12-24T11:13:00', 511.22, 515.30, 505.49, 506.47]
 ...
```

Comment: Please provide a snippet of your code so it’s easier to troubleshoot

Comment: I'v added code example and images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you set the dates in different formats. If you want to show not only a date but also time you should make all the x values have hours, minutes, etc. Please check this [sample](https://playground.anychart.com/37smwQLi/0).

Comment: I set a data always with a same datetime format. Even, when the data has only hours, I have minutes and seconds with zero values. Like I showed in the topic post, I've used the same format for two data set and I had a different result. 

Although, I've noticed in your example, that sometimes there is no time at all on the chart and sometimes wrong formatting appear again.
Please, try to add to the sample two values at the beginning:
['2015-12-24T08:13:00', 511.53, 514.98, 505.79, 506.40],
['2015-12-24T09:13:00', 512.53, 514.88, 505.69, 510.34]

Comment: yes, Dmitry, this is the default behavior. The format is being selected depending on the interval between given points. And this interval is calculated automatically. Here we got 'full_year_hour': 'HH dd MMM yyyy'. But we can format the dates in the tooltip title like this: `anychart.format.outputDateTimeFormat('dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss');
tooltip.titleFormat(function () {
    return anychart.format.dateTime(this.x)
  });`
Check the sample here: https://playground.anychart.com/tHNaoDAh

Learn more about formatting: 
https://api.anychart.com/anychart.format#outputDateTimeFormat

Comment: The advise with tooltip.titleFormat really helpful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do you apply any formatting settings for the labels? Please, provide us with the code to let us review it. In any case, the problem can be solved with the formatting settings. For example, you can use the following lines to format xAxis labels:

```
this.chart.plot(0).xAxis().labels().format('{%tickValue}{dateTimeFormat:dd MMM yyyy hh:mm}');
this.chart.plot(0).xAxis().minorLabels().format('{%tickValue}{dateTimeFormat:dd MMM yyyy hh:mm}');
```

Comment: Thank you for response. But, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I still have the same result. I'v just added code example and images to describe more precisely to the topic post. 
Yes, I've tried to use different formatting, but the result is the same.

Comment: I'v met the same problem in playground
https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/STOCK_Data_01
when I replace some date with datetime. 

For example, replacing first value in data array (2015-12-24 with 2015-12-24T23:13:00) will reproduce my problem.

Also, I've checked all incoming data - they are all correct and well formatted from backend

Comment: Thank you for the screenshots! Now I see that we didn't understand you correctly in the beginning, the issue is related to the tooltip title. You can solve it using titleFormat function. Just add the following line to your code `chart.tooltip().titleFormat('{%x}{dateTimeFormat:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm}');`. Just like it shown in the following sample - https://playground.anychart.com/5QrPgf3D